# how to send a multiple message using datagridview in selecting a checkbox in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code:

```
'for clicking the datagridview

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        Try
            MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; User=root;Password='';Database=lrbhams;"


            MySqlConnection.Open()
            Dim state3 As String = "select boarder_fname, boarder_contact, guardian, guardian_number from boarders_info"
            Dim command As New MySqlCommand(state3, MySqlConnection)
            'command.Connection.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MySqlConnection.Close()

            If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value Then
                TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value

            ElseIf DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Value Then
                TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Value
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        ''
    End Sub
```

For sending message:

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        Dim message As String
        'Dim reader As MySqlDataReader


        message = RichTextBox1.Text
    If send_sms.SerialPort.PortName = send_sms.portName Then
        send_sms.SerialPort.Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
        send_sms.SerialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
        send_sms.SerialPort.Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & TextBox1.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
        send_sms.SerialPort.Write(message & Chr(26))
        MsgBox("Text Message Successfully Send !!!")
        Try

            Dim connectString As String
            Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
            Dim command As MySqlCommand
            'Dim mysqlQuery As String

            connectString = "server=localhost;user=root;database=lrbhams"
            conn = New MySqlConnection(connectString)

            Dim query As String
            conn.Open()
            query = "INSERT into admin_log_attendance (action,contact_number, date) VALUES ('" & RichTextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & Date.Today & "')"

            command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
            reader = Command.ExecuteReader
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You'd immediately write better code if you avoided `Catch ex As Exception` especially if you then only do `MsgBox(ex.Message)`.

Comment: What is the actual problem?  Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, are you sure your code continue before this section? send_sms.SerialPort.PortName = send_sms.portName. Try this: MessageBox.Show("message", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.Yesl)

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: @Mary Thank you. I will try it

Answer (score 0):

`MySqlConnection` is a class in the `MySql.Data.MySqlClien`t namespace. It is not a static class so it must be instantiated with the New keyword. You cannot set properties or call methods on the class itself. You must created an instance of the class. It is best practice to use `Using...End Using blocks for database objects. It will ensure that the database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

A `Select` statement is not a NonQuery. Insert, Update and Delete statements can be run with `command.ExecuteNonQuery` but not `Select`. A `Select` query can be run with `.ExecuteScalar` if a single piece of data is expected or `.ExecuteReader` if several columns and/or rows are expected.

You can't just execute a `Select` command and expect something to happen. I suspect you want to display the data in your grid so let's fill a `DataTable` (an in memory representation of the records returned) with the `.Load` method then bind it to the `DataGridView`.

No need to close the connection because the Using block will close it.

If you call `.ToString` on a class that doesn't override the method you will just get the fully qualified name of the class. The `Exception` class provides a `Property` called `Message` which you can use.

The filling of the `DataGridView` will go in a separate method which you can call from `Form.Load`.

Now that there is data in the `DataGridView` you can click on it and the `CellContentClick` event will fire. I hope Cell(2) and Cell(4) Booleans because that is the only why your `If` statement will work. The necessity of the conversion code and `.ToString` will be obvious once you turn on Option Strict. (See my comment)

That's enough for now. With all this and Option Strict you should be able to fix the second part of your code.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RetrieveRecordsForDataGridView()
End Sub

Private Sub RetrieveRecordsForDataGridView()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; User=root;Password='';Database=lrbhams;")
            Dim state3 As String = "select boarder_fname, boarder_contact, guardian, guardian_number from boarders_info"
            Using command As New MySqlCommand(state3, cn)
                cn.Open()
                dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader())
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    If CBool(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value) Then
        TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value.ToString
    ElseIf CBool(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Value) Then
        TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Value.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```